# XConnect Indexer Log Huge

Tags: xconnect

I have a Sitecore 9 XP1 topology installed, and
**XConnect Collection Search** role from time to time generate logs files bigger than 1GB, and as it is a development environment, this is causing my server to run out of disk space every 2 days.

The file is located at **XConnect Collection Search** instance on App_data\jobs\continuous\IndexWorker\App_data\Logs

Here is how the entries looks like

> 2018-06-25 00:00:00.010 -04:00 [Error] An error occured.
>   System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Response status code does not indicate success: 500 (Server Error).
>      at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.Search.Solr.SolrClient.d__4.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.Search.Solr.SolrRebuildStatusStorage.d__5.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at Sitecore.XConnect.Search.Indexer.IndexerHost.d__28.MoveNext()

Any ideas why am I getting such errors?

Comment: Are you starting rebuild process (log mentions SolrRebuildStatusStorage)?

Comment: I don't think it is during rebuild process...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the error message, it looks like you are getting a 500 error when it is attempting to contact Solr. I would check to make sure your Solr instance is up and running and look at the logs on the Solr side to make sure you aren't having a bunch of errors over there.

Comment: Looks like you hit the target MR. Jay S! I accessed couple SOLR tied to the Sitecore projects and found multiple errors which may be the real reason of this is happening.